# TD not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, html-table, background, margin

```
<tr> 
    <td></td> 
    <td colspan="3">Susi Handayani Jl. Kebangsaan No.225 300.000</td> 
</tr>
```

How to merge the two td to be inside one Td, but it's not sticking together, merged but I want the word to not stick together beside, make some space from the deleted td to be the same column as above

I tried align but it didn't Work, I've also tried dividing the tr and tried removing td for one paragraph and it still sticks with the second paragraph (td), what I'd expect is the td not to stick together but to align the text above the text that I've made

```
<h3>Tabel HTML</h3>
<table>
<caption>Tabel Simpanan Peserta</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Nama Peserta</th>
      <th>Alamat</th>
      <th>Simpanan</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Total</td>
    <td>350.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>Andi Suryono</td>
      <td>Jl. Kemerdekaan No.17</td>
    <td>50.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
        <td colspan="3">Susi Handayani
        Jl. Kebangsaan No.225
        300.000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>Roy Pratama</td>
        <td>Jl. Merdeka No.32</td>
      <td>1.000.000</td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td>Tia Suryani</td>
      <td>Jl. Jelajah No.111</td>
    <td>1.555.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to make the table fused but not sticking together, I'm planning to give the word some space and how do I make the space for each column

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about styling, yet you posted no style tag or CSS whatsoever. Post the general CSS you have, to reproduce the problem, or at least a screenshot of what the problem is.

Generally, spacing in tables comes with padding. Try something like:

```
<style>
td { 
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
</style>
```

This will put 5px top and bottom and 10px from both sides of every cell in the table.

Comment: <style>
    table  {
      border-collapse:collapse;
      border-spacing:0;     
      border:1px black solid;
      width:40%;
    }
    th, td {
      padding:10px 20px;
      border:1px black solid;}
    th{
      background-color: #87F97B;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #FDA; 
    }
  </style>

here is the css also thanks for the answer,i'll try it out

Comment: Seems working to me, check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6vfgdnj4/